# S4 extension of data.frame class

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I want to define new S4 class that extends data.frame (e.g. make use of print generic). This new class should have two numeric slots but be represented in the form of data frame. I tried following:

```
df_ts <- setClass("df_ts",
     slots = list(time = "numeric", value = "numeric"),
     contains = "data.frame",
     validity = function(object){
       if (length(object@time) != length(object@value)){
         return("Vectors not equal!")
       } else{
         TRUE
       }
     })
```

When I try to initalize it with:

```
exmp <- df_ts(time=1:10, value=rnorm(10))
```

I get empty data frame but the data are still stored in slots. The question is how can I properly extend data frame class? Would it be better to use S3 classes?

Comment: What is your expectation of the verb "extend"? Doing this to get the contents printed with `print.generic` doesn't make much sense unless you say what that function is supposed to do. Would also seem that you would want a slot for some data..

Comment: @42 extend - I want to inherit some methods of data frame. But it is not possible as the data are stored in slots. I know I can make use of slots using e.g data.frame(time = exmp@time, value = exmp@value) but then it would not be df_ts class.

Comment: It appears you want to create a data.frame class where all columns are enforced to be numeric. First, have you considered that a matrix might be the more appropriate data structure?

Comment: Might be an X-Y problem. Might help to describe the goals of this effort. S4 structures can hold S3 structures, even those which have a class vector that looks like `c("my_special_dfrm", " data.frame")`, so I'm not seeing any difficulty.